# Why does my proprietary file format fail to unarchive?

Tags: actionscript-3, filestream

I've got a proprietary file format that works as an archive.  It takes a folder full of files and packs them into a single file with no compression - the first X bytes of the files are dedicated to the "Table of contents" - the file paths, their size in bytes and their location (byte index) in the archive file. the remaining bytes are for the actual data of each file.

This format works and has been working for several years except in a few cases I am trying to debug.  There are some cases where the files fail to unarchive properly In my experience this is typically on laptops which I presume have 5400 rpm hard drives. But sometimes it fail on SSD hard drives (like a Surface Book)  Also the failure is not consistent.  If I were to unarchive the same file 10 times on a "problem" machine it might only fail 1 or 2 times or not at all in some cases.

In the language that I am unarchiving this format (as3), the file stream reader has  property 'readAhead' - which as the docs indicate is 'The minimum amount of data to read from disk when reading files asynchronously'  .  Could this value be affecting my unarchiving?  My initial value for this was '8192' which I have now changed to 8192/4 to test on some new machines.  Anyone have any thoughts on this? Is the readAhead value irrelevant?

I realize this is vague.  I'm not looking for a specific solution just want to get some feedback from people who have more experience on how I could better diagnose and resolve this issue.

Here is the class in question.  I've tried to remove anything unrelated to what I'm asking about:

```
/**
     * ...
     * @author Phil
     */
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.Endian;

    public class Archive extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public static const UNARCHIVING_COMPLETE:String = "unarchivingComplete";        
        public static const UNARCHIVING_PROGRESS:String = "unarchivingProgress";        
        public static const UNARCHIVE_CANCEL:String = "unarchiveCancel";

        public static const ENDIAN:String = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;       

        private var _inputFile:File;
        private var _outputFile:File;

        private var _inputStream:FileStream;
        private var _outputStream:FileStream;

        private var _files:Vector.<ArchiveItem>;
        private var _readAheadValue:uint = 8192 / 4;        
        private var _maxTableSize:uint =  40960 * 30;
        private var _tableData:ByteArray;

        private var _curArchiveItem:ArchiveItem;
        private var _currentArchiveItemBytesWritten:uint;

        private var _pointerPosition:uint = 0;
        private var _tableSize:uint = 0;
        private var _totalSize:uint = 0;
        private var _totalFiles:uint = 0;

        public function Archive() 
        {

        }

        public function readArchive(archive:File, dest:File):void 
        {
            _inputFile = archive;
            _outputFile = dest;

            createReadStream();         

            createTableData();

            _inputStream.openAsync( _inputFile, FileMode.READ );            
        }

        public function destroy():void 
        {
            killStreams();
            _inputFile = null;
            _outputFile = null;     
        }

        public function cancel():void 
        {
            killStreams();          
        }   

        private function killStreams():void 
        {
            killInStream();
            killOutStream();
        }

        private function killInStream():void 
        {
            if (!_inputStream) return;

            _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileReadComplete);
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onFileReadProgress);           
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArhiveReadComplete);
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onTableReadProgress);              
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onArchiveReadProgress);
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onInputClosed);                   
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErrorReadingArchive);

            _inputStream.close();

            _inputStream = null;
        }

        private function killOutStream():void 
        {
            if (!_outputStream) return; 

            _outputStream.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);            
            _outputStream.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onOutPutClosed);         

            _outputStream.close();

            _outputStream = null;
        }

        private function createTableData():void 
        {
            _files = new Vector.<ArchiveItem>();
            _tableData = new ByteArray();
            _tableData.endian = ENDIAN;
        }

        private function createReadStream():void 
        {
            _inputStream = new FileStream();
            _inputStream.endian = ENDIAN;
            _inputStream.readAhead = _readAheadValue;

            _inputStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onInputClosed);
            _inputStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArhiveReadComplete);
            _inputStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onTableReadProgress); 
            _inputStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErrorReadingArchive);
        }

        private function onErrorReadingArchive(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
        {
            dispatchEvent( new Event(Event.CANCEL) );
        }

        private function onArhiveReadComplete(e:Event):void 
        {           
            if (_tableData.length < _maxTableSize)
            {
                onTableReadProgress( null, true);
            }
        }

        private function onTableReadProgress(e:ProgressEvent, force:Boolean = false):void 
        {           
            if (_tableData.length < _maxTableSize && force == false)
            {
                _inputStream.readBytes( _tableData,_tableData.length );
            }else {

                _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArhiveReadComplete);
                _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onTableReadProgress);

                populateTable( _tableData );
            }

            return;

            if (_inputStream.bytesAvailable < _maxTableSize && force == false)
            {
                return;
            }else {
                _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArhiveReadComplete);
                _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onTableReadProgress);

                var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                ba.endian = ENDIAN;             

                _inputStream.readBytes(ba);

                populateTable( ba   );              
            }
        }

        private function populateTable(tableData:ByteArray):void
        {           
            var a:ArchiveItem;
            var offset:uint = 0;
            var size:uint = 0;
            var fileName:String;

            if (tableData is ByteArray)
            {
                tableData.position = 0;
            }           

            for (;;)
            {
                offset = tableData.readUnsignedInt();
                size = tableData.readUnsignedInt();
                fileName = tableData.readUTF();

                if (fileName == "endTable")
                {                   
                    _tableSize = tableData.position;

                    _totalFiles = _files.length;

                    _totalSize = _inputFile.size;

                    completeTableRead();

                    break;
                }

                a = new ArchiveItem();
                a.filename = fileName;
                a.offset = offset;
                a.size = size;

                _files.push(a);
            }
        }

        private function completeTableRead():void 
        {               
            createFileOutputStream();           

            _inputStream.readAhead = _readAheadValue;
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArhiveReadComplete);
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onTableReadProgress);
            _inputStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onArchiveReadProgress);
            _inputStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArchiveReadProgress);

            writeNextArchiveItemToFile();           
        }

        private function onInputClosed(e:Event):void 
        {           
            completeUnarchiving();          
        }

        private function completeUnarchiving():void 
        {   
            killStreams();

            dispatchEvent( new Event(UNARCHIVING_COMPLETE) );
        }

        private function createFileOutputStream():void 
        {
            _outputStream = new FileStream();           
            _outputStream.endian = ENDIAN;
            _outputStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onOutPutClosed);        
            _outputStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        }

        private function onOutPutClosed(e:Event):void 
        {
            completeUnarchiving();
        }   

        private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
        {
            dispatchEvent( new Event(Event.CANCEL) );
        }

        private function writeNextArchiveItemToFile():void 
        {
            if (_files.length == 0)
            {                               
                endWriting();
                return;
            }   

            _curArchiveItem = _files.shift();           
            _currentArchiveItemBytesWritten = 0;

            var dest:File = new File();
            dest.nativePath = _outputFile.nativePath + File.separator + _curArchiveItem.filename;

            _outputStream.open(dest, FileMode.WRITE);

            movePointer();          
        }   

        private function endWriting():void 
        {               
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onArchiveReadProgress);
            _inputStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArchiveReadProgress);        

            _outputStream.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);            

            _outputStream.close();
            _inputStream.close();           
        }


        private function onOutputStreamCloseOnCompelte(e:Event):void 
        {       
            dispatchEvent( new Event(UNARCHIVING_COMPLETE) );
        }

        private function movePointer():void 
        {       
            _inputStream.position = _tableSize + _curArchiveItem.offset;    

            _pointerPosition = _inputStream.position;

            if (_curArchiveItem.size == 0)
            {
                writeNextArchiveItemToFile();           
            }
        }

        private function onArchiveReadProgress(e:Event):void 
        {
            if (_currentArchiveItemBytesWritten >= _curArchiveItem.size)
            {
                writeNextArchiveItemToFile();
                return;
            }

            writeBytesToDisk();
        }

        private function writeBytesToDisk():void 
        {           
            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

            var bytesRemaining:uint = _curArchiveItem.size - _currentArchiveItemBytesWritten;
            var bytesToWrite:uint = _inputStream.bytesAvailable;
            if (bytesToWrite > bytesRemaining)
            {
                bytesToWrite = bytesRemaining;
            }

            _inputStream.readBytes(bytes, 0, bytesToWrite);
            try {
                _outputStream.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length); //This throws an error on large files.
            }catch (e:Error)
            {           
                dispatchEvent( new Event(Event.CANCEL) );
                return;
            }           

            _currentArchiveItemBytesWritten += bytes.length;                

            _pointerPosition = _inputStream.position;

            dispatchEvent( new Event(UNARCHIVING_PROGRESS) );

            if (_currentArchiveItemBytesWritten >= _curArchiveItem.size)
            {               
                writeNextArchiveItemToFile();
            }
        }

    }
}
class ArchiveItem
{
    public var offset:uint;
    public var size:uint;       
    public var filename:String;

    public function ArchiveItem()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can really help you on this. You create your own archiver/unarchiver and without showing any code you expect that someone could help you fix it. Not gonna happen.

Comment: As I stated in my closing statement. I'm not looking for any specific help just some insight and any suggestions someone might have.  I appreciate the feedback nonetheless.

Comment: I understand but even if somebody tries that would just be a shot in the dark with very little chance to be of any help.

Comment: @Phil Is there a reason you can't post the actual encoding/decoding code?

Comment: My guess is that he doesn't want to post the code cos he's afraid people will steal it, we can understand that, but at the same time he needs help to make his code work and he can't get any without showing any code. He's stuck in limbo here, he shows code he gets help, he doesn't, he needs to figure it out himself.

Comment: There is a lot of code.  I just wanted to get some feedback first.  I'll try to post a simplified example later today.

Comment: It's not so much that I am worried people will steal it, it's just integrated (poorly) into some other code.  I just need to extract it and make the most elementary example.

Comment: I've updated the post with some code.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This was too long for comments..

Just my personal opinion but I think you've over-cooked a simple task. Your usage of `.readAhead` is confusing. For un-archive part why not have..

**(1)** On startup your app creates & fills an **[Object](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)** with entries **parsed** from table of contents (myself I'd just make & update 3 arrays noting **file Names**, **Sizes** and also the **Indices** within the archive file).

**(2)** For extracting say the 5th file in archive you just check `dest_Name = fileNames[4];` for expected output name String, then also note expected `dest_Size = size[4];` integer (length to extract).

**(3)** Now just read the archive file (on disk) and get that 5th file saved.

```
Archive_Stream.openAsync( URL_Archive_File, FileMode.READ ); 
Archive_Stream.position = dest_indexInArchive[4]; //starting index
```

The above would read bytes into a `temp_BA` which can then be saved (when READ is complete, the handler function does a WRITE to disk of that single extracted file). Now you can use `temp_BA.clear();` to reset and clear it for a different file (or just reclaim memory used).